# angular $resource GET item is generating wrong api request

Tags: angularjs

whenever i'm calling GET item in angular the api URL is not what i expect, and i can't find anything wrong with it.

my resource

```
angular.module('app').factory('mvCourse', function($resource) {
    var CourseResource = $resource('/api/courses/:id', {_id: "@id"});

    return CourseResource;
});
```

which you can see i expect the call to be `http://localhost/api/courses/53f05bb649d473da3fb83b59` but what am getting is `http://localhost:1337/api/courses?_id=53f05bb649d473da3fb83b59`

my api call is as follow

```
angular.module('app').controller('mvCourseDetailCtrl', function ($scope,$routeParams,mvCourse) {
    $scope.course = mvCourse.get({_id:$routeParams.id});
});
```

i'm using

```
"angular-resource": "~1.2.21",
"angular": "~1.2.21",
```

Comment: You could change `_id` to `id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that changing `_id` to `id` would do the trick, as found in help in comments

Comment: can't do so before 2 days, maybe @runTarm can submit an answer